# In cuda, loading to shared memory is slower than loading to registers

Tags: c, performance, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm not an experienced CUDA programmer. I got a problem like this.
I'm trying to load a 32x32 tile of a large 10Kx10K matrix from global memory into shared memory and I'm timing it while it happens. I realized that If I load it to private memory (registers), it loads 4-5 times faster than shared memory loading.

```
__global__ void speedtest( float *vel,int nx) {

    int globalx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x+pad;
    int globalz = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y+pad;
    int localx=threadIdx.x;
    int localz=threadIdx.y;

    float ptest;
    __shared__ float stest[tile][tile];

    //stest[localz][localx]=vel[globalz*nx+globalx]; //load to shared memory
    ptest=vel[globalz*nx+globalx];  //load to private memory
    __syncthreads();
}
```

I comment out `stest` and `ptest` one by one and calculate elapsed time with `cudaeventrecord`. `stest` took 3.2 ms and `ptest` took 0.75ms to load. What am I doing wrong? Timings should be very similar right? What am I missing?

Configuration: CUDA 7.5, GTX 980, only 32bit variables and calculations, no specific purpose is intended, I'm just playing with it.

I'm posting sample code as requested

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define tile 32
#include <helper_cuda.h>
void makeittwo(float *array,int nz,int nx)
{
    //this just assigns a number into the vector
    int n2;
    n2=nx*nz;
    for (int i=0;i<n2;i++)
        array[i]=2000;
}

__global__ void speedtest( float *vel,int nx,int nz) {

    int globalx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int globalz = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int localx=threadIdx.x;
    int localz=threadIdx.y;

    float ptest; //declarations
    __shared__ float stest[tile][tile];

    if (globalx<nx && globalz<nz){
        stest[localz][localx]=vel[globalz*nx+globalx]; //shared variable
        //ptest=vel[globalz*nx+globalx];                        //private variable

        //comment out ptest and stest one by one to test them  
    }
    __syncthreads();

}       

int main(int argc,char *argv)
{
    int nx,nz,N;
    float *vel;

    nz=10000;nx=10000; //matrix dimensions
    N=nz*nx; //convert matrix into vector

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocHost(&vel,sizeof(float)*N)); //using pinned memory
    makeittwo(vel,nz,nx);

    dim3 dimBlock(tile,tile);
    dim3 dimGrid;

    int blockx=dimBlock.x;
    int blockz=dimBlock.y;

    dimGrid.x = (nx + blockx - 1) / (blockx);
    dimGrid.y = (nz + blockz - 1) / (blockz);

    float *d_vel;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_vel,sizeof(float)*(N))); //copying to device
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_vel, vel, sizeof(float)*(N), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);
    speedtest<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_vel,nx,nz); //calling the function
    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime,start,stop);

    printf("time=%3.3f ms\n",elapsedTime);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(vel, d_vel, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); 
    //calling the matrix back  to check if all went well (this fails if out of bound calls are made)

    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

Comment: You are not measuring what you expect to measure: In the "register code" the assignment is completely optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: How could it be? They both access the global data in the same pattern, both wait for sync. I also tried first loading to register then loading from register to shared memory if there is any speed up, there is none. There is no bank conflict in shared memory. Link speed and latency between global to shared memory and global to register should be similar i think.

Comment: In the "register example" you are not doing anything with the variable, the compiler is free to remove it. In the "shared memory" example the compiler probably does not remove the load because other threads might use the values stored in shared memory. (Actually I would have thought the compiler will optimize away the load to shared memory  as well since it is never read, but it doesn't...)

Comment: By the way, the load to shared memory goes through registers. It is loaded to register from global memory, then stored in shared memory.

Comment: to make sure register memory doesn't get removed. I calculated ptest*=ptest and stest*=stest. Still ptest is 4 times faster. Then later I decided to write them back to original global memory,then timings become equal magically. I couldn't understand a thing. Is link direction matter for speed?

Comment: `ptest*=ptest` does not change anything. Is is removed by the compiler... One possibility would be to store the value back to global memory as you mentioned. Then the compiler cannot remove the instruction. However, in that case you are measuring read and write. What do you mean by link direction?

Comment: "Then later I decided to write them back to original global memory,then timings become equal magically."  As @havogt has said several times now, the compiler is optimizing the code you write.  You may not understand the extent of this.  Code that does not affect global state *can be removed by the compiler*.  This method of performance analysis by commenting out lines of code can be fraught with error, especially for beginners.  There are many questions like this one on the cuda tag here on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example code actually does not measure what the OP expects to measure, because some instructions are optimized away by the compiler.

In the **local variable** example (`ptest`) the load does not affect the state outside of the kernel. In this case the compiler is free to remove the instruction completely. This can be seen in the SASS code. The SASS code is same when `ptest=vel[globalz*nx+globalx];` is active or both statements (ptest and stest) are removed. To inspect the SASS code you can run `cuobjdump --dump-sass` on the object file.

Apparently, the instructions are not optimized away in the **shared memory** example as can be checked in SASS code. (Actually, I would have expected the instructions are removed as well. Are there side-effects that miss?)

As already discussed in the comments, with a simple calculation (`ptest*=ptest`) **and** a write to global memory the compiler cannot remove the instruction because it changes the global state.

From the comments of the OP I assume that there is a misunderstanding in how the load operation to shared memory works. Actually the **data is loaded from global memory to registers and then stored in shared memory**.
The (relevant) SASS instructions (for sm_30) that are generated look like this

```
LD.E R2, [R6]; // load to register R2
STS [R0], R2; // store from register R2 to shared memory
```

The following **multiply and store to global memory** example demonstrates another case where the compiler does not produce code that one may naively expect:

```
stest[localz][localx]=vel[globalz*nx+globalx]; // load to shared memory
stest[localz][localx]*=stest[localz][localx]; // multiply
vel[globalz*nx+globalx]=stest[localz][localx]; // save to global memory
```

The SASS code shows that the variable is only stored in shared memory after the computation (and never read form shared memory).

```
LD.E R2, [R6]; // load to register
FMUL R0, R2, R2; // multiply
STS [R3], R0; // store the result in shared memory
ST.E [R6], R0; // store the result in global memory
```

I am not really an expert in SASS code, please correct me if I am wrong or left out anything important.

Comment: I further analyzed the code, I realized that if I wont load anything or use a statement like ptest=0, same timing is recorded (0.75ms). It is apparent to me now that compiler is ignoring my unnecessary instructions. I was measuring empty kernel timing while running ptest benchmark. It would be better if nvidia had done "optimization" on shared memory too to avoid confusion